# Correct Usage: But for your charm or But for your charms?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

Are both of these correct usage:

1. But for your **charm** I wouldn't have stayed back.
2. But for your **charms** I wouldn't have stayed back.

If both of these are correct usage then are the meanings same in both the cases?

Comment: Both are valid.  The difference is subtle and would depend a lot on context.

Comment: Agree with @Hot Licks.

Comment: Does the person have uncountable charm (an overall quality)—or do they have countable charms, and several of them?

Comment: From my experience number 2 would be the more common usage. It lets you equivocate on just which of the many charms are responsible.